# Move to parent activity without finishing child activity using back button

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to go one activity back without finishing the one you're leaving?
In my android app, I have a drawer activity, which with a drawer item click opens a new activity. However, when I try to move back to the drawer activity using the back button, the newly opened activity is destroyed. Is it possible to move that activity back so it runs in background?

Comment: There are means of stack management, for example, through intent flagging. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` may help you here.

Comment: Do I pass that flag to the MainActivity intent that launches the SecondActivity? Or override onBackPressed() and launch MainActivity from SecondActivity?

Comment: The second one, override onBackPressed and trigger the new intent.

Comment: Hey @Kamihan the use case you are trying to implement is best solved using [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). I strongly recommend to use these instead of making the app tightly coupled.

Comment: @zgc7009 I tried that, it didn't work. The second activity gets destroyed. :(

Comment: @code-crusher You're suggesting to turn the second activity (that needs to run in background) into a fragment for the drawer? I already tried that a bit, but it didn't work, so I just reverted, since there's some extra issues I'd have to take care of by doing that.

Comment: @Kamihan fragments can be kept in back-stacking for such purposes. When you switch fragments they keep cache of an instance. The issue you are facing with that will be easier to solve. :)

Comment: @code-crusher Alright, I'll try that, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Move from drawer activity to next activity by setting the flag to clear the stack and now stack only has one activity which need to run in background now open drawer activity.

i.e

A => drawer activity

B => activity which need to run in background

Step-1

open A

now stack has only A

---

Step-2

move from A -> B by clearing the flag

now stack has only B

---

Step-3

move from B -> A

now stack has only B and A. A is on top of stack and B is still in stack

Comment: It did not work. On activity B I have a boolean isRunning that is set to true at onResume, and false to onPause. I also have Log.d(); set up to let me know when it is running, and when it's not. When the second activity is on, it says that activity is running, when I click the back button though, it does not log anything. The logging works fine if I hit home button though. :/